# Disable HDMI Interface to achieve a lower power footprint

Tags: hdmi, power

Is it possible, to turn off the HDMI video component? My Pi operates headless so there ist no need for me to have a video out component. 
If yes, how much power will be saved?

Comment: You can save more power by [disabling the usb-controller](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8498/disable-lan9512).

Answer (score 8):

I think you can just switch it off, but I do not know how much power is saved.

**Switch off**

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o
```

**Switch on**

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p
```