# Booting from HDMI

Tags: boot, hdmi

I was wondering if it's possible that you can boot a RaspberryPI from a HDMI. We want to place one behind and connected to TV. Is there a way that it is able to boot if the HDMI port source is select on the TV. This happens with my xBox, if I select the xBox HDMI it will automatically turn it on as well. I have tried Googling this the last few days without any success.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "boot"?  Have you an example of any device which can be "booted" from HDMI?

Comment: you cannot boot from HDMI ... you can boot from and SD card ... your X-Box does not boot from HDMI either, it boots from a hard drive, or from SSD

Comment: I think the spirit of the question is clear, if the wording could be better. Kurtis wants to cause his Pi to boot when the TV input to which it is connected is selected. (I have no idea whether it is possible.)

Answer (score 2):

I think what the XBox is doing is that it is running in a low power mode when idle, and is able to detect when the TV selects its HDMI port as the source. When it detects that, it boots the full XBox operating system, and the fan and LEDs turns on. You want the same functionality with the Raspberry Pi.

As far as I know, there is no readily available software to do exactly that. I think most people just leave their Raspberry Pis on, since it is a fairly low power device by default.

There are a few questions here that try to optimize power usage (e.g. [How to achieve Low Power Consumption on Raspberry Pi via Software and Hardware control](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33723/how-to-achieve-low-power-consumption-on-raspberry-pi-via-software-and-hardware-c)), and perhaps it would be possible to configure the Pi to lower its power usage slightly when idle, and then re-enable things like USB ports when the TV selects its HDMI port (presumably it would be detected somehow with HDMI-CEC). I am not aware of any existing software that does this.