# Is there a way to disable the LAN9512 on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, ethernet

I've seen articles describing how to disable LAN on the RPi 1 Model B. But it's not working on my RPi 2 Model B. According to [Disable LAN9512](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8498/disable-lan9512) the command is supposed to be:
`echo 0x0 > /sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/buspower` to disable it, but that doesn't work on my device as I don't have the `bcm2708_usb` part.

Here is an output of `ls -l /sys/devices/platform/`

```
pi@raspberrypi /sys/devices/platform $ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 alarmtimer

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD0.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD1.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD2.2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD3.3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD4.4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD5.5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD6.6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 bcm2835_AUD7.7
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 clocks
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 serial8250
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    0 Dec 10 02:05 soc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec 10 02:08 timer
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Dec 10 02:05 uevent
```

I'm looking for a solution to disable the LAN because my aim is to turn off the chip that provides power to the LAN as I would like to run a test to utilise the cpu only and measure its power consumption.

Comment: What are you trying to gain by doing this?

Comment: Need to be more specific. Note that the LAN9512 not only handles LAN but also USB. So while your title says to disable the whole chip (aka including USB) the text suggests that only the LAN should be disabled. (Adding to the obious *why?*).

Comment: Thanks for the response. My aim is to turn off the chip that provides power to the LAN as I would like to run a test to utilise the cpu only and measure its power consumption. If turning off the LAN wud also turn off the USB, then so be it. But i need to turn it off. I note that there is a simple solution for older RPis (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8498/disable-lan9512) but the path seems different in RPi 2.

Comment: @ACG can you post the output of `ls -l /sys/devices/platform/` then? I do have `/sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/buspower` on my Pi 2. But I just executed `echo 0x0 > /sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/buspower` and got an error. If you do too, then please add that info too to your question.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas. I've posted the output put its not formatted to be easily read.

Comment: My instructions were incorrect as it doesn't seem to support triple  backticks (backtick = left of 1 on my keyboard; not apostrophes), but I've now fixed it.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas If you are going to post formatting instructions you should read http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for the pointer :-) Didn't realize that 3 backticks is (apparently) GitHub's extension.

Comment: Its only one needed (or a <pre> ... </pre> tag pair) - but on some systems/keyboard configuration getting a back tick means pressing the key twice (git hub really stresses the key below my ESC one!)