# I need to ifdown ifup for real

Tags: networking, linux

I am trying to simulate disconnecting the network cable from a pi.

So how do I invoke this?  I've tried ifdown / ifup in various different forms.

When I say simulate, you may ask yourself on what level.  All, the system must behave as though there has been a break at layer 1 OSI(physical).

Now maybe I sound a bit too stringent in my question, I don't want to go touching drivers and anything on the kernel level.

What I have so far is this, and my ultimate question is:
I have a console cable to my cisco router.  It has a switch EHWIC card, to which my pi is connected, to one of the ports.

From pi in terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

And the router reports the interface goes down on layer 3 and layer 2. and then up again.
Is this the closest I am going to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the closest I am going to get?

Going about it this way, yes.  The up/down state of a network interface may change as the consequence of a layer 1 event, but it obviously isn't in itself.  It's a data link/network layer concern.

I would look into powering off the ethernet controller, which is also the USB controller:

[Disable LAN9512](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/8498/5538)

Glancing through `/sys` on a B+ running a current kernel (4.9.30+) it looks like this stuff has changed a bit; look in `/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb`; `buspower` and `bussuspend` are writable.  The problem then is how to input to the Pi with the USB and ethernet turned off.

Comment: this sounds like a feasible solution for me actually.  It's a power down and up I am looking for and it can be controlled with a delay in between.  Thank you for your reply, power off the USB controller, I never looked at that way :)

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt there is a way to simulate a physical break using software only. You will probably have to resort to disconnecting the physical cable or installing smell kind of physical switch in the cable.