# Powering the PI 3 Model B with a battery pack

Tags: pi-3, battery

I've recently obtained a Pi 3 Model B, with the official 7 inch touchscreen case, as well as the allied electronics portable case and I am looking at options to provide power to it. Currently, from looking at the documentation on the [official](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#power) site as well as [this blog](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-do-i-power-my-raspberry-pi), the recommended option is to use a 5.25V/2.4A Micro USB AC Power Supply. I have one, however, I would like a more portable means of providing power to it. So far, the best solution I have found is using a portable phone charger.

So I guess my question is, what are my best options in terms of long-term battery life? Also, is there a way to monitor the battery life on the PI once its connected to the battery pack? Ideally, I would like to use this as a computer (note taking, drawing, surfing the net) and perhaps even connect a second monitor to work with my 7 inch screen.

Comment: Any 5V battery will power the Pi - the question is for how long. Any battery you can squeeze into an existing case isn't going to last long.

Comment: The answer to your battery life question can be found here --> http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48043/application-to-know-how-long-my-batteries-will-last

Comment: I would be very hesitant to plug any unregulated battery pack to the pi as they seem to be sensitive to spikes and over voltage.

Answer (score 1):

There's 3 options for powering the Pi & 7" screen. I think the screen requires at least 500mA, and the Pi3 requires 2.5A. To power both from a single battery means you'll need a battery pack that can support 3A output from a single USB connection. Or a battery with 2 outputs, at least 2.5A on one and 500mA on the other. Or two battery packs.

Options for connecting the screen to the Pi and providing power are described here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/

Answer (score 1):

I just went through 3 batteries (chargers), and finally found one that works (with some issue, read edit below).   My first battery was a 2.1A single output (was not enough and I got the lightning bolt and downlclocking).   The second battery I got was a 2.4A single output (was not enough and I got the lightning bolt and downlclocking) (This confused me, because my 2.4A wall plug works just fine).

The 3rd battery I got is a 3.4A Total output.   There are 2 outputs, with a maximum of 2.4A out of each (up to 3.4A).

I disconnected the LCD and Pi power link, and I am powering them now separately with 2 cords from my new battery.  IT works!!  Yippee!!..

The Pass-through also works, but you must shut down the pi before plugging it in, or it will reboot you Pi.

Here is the battery that works...
https://www.amazon.ca/Portable-RAVPower-Li-polymer-Technology-Smartphone/dp/B01M69SVPU/ref=sr_1_1?rps=1&ie=UTF8&qid=1497042513&sr=8-1&keywords=Portable+Charger+RAVPower+12000mAh

EDIT:   I Ran into issues with the power button on this supply.  It does not work as an 'Off' switch, and the USB's are automatically engaged when something is drawing from them.   So, I used an old PC Power supply switch, which is a 2 pole switch, and wired up both of my USB reds to that.   It works perfectly!.

So, at the end of the day, this battery does work well, and it is a good size, but you will need to deal with wiring a power switch between it and the Pi.