# Best Way To Power Raspberry Pi Zero and External 4.5 - 36v Circuit

Tags: gpio, hardware, power-supply, pi-zero, alternative-power

I am creating a drone where I have a Raspberry Pi Zero, and a [Motozero](https://thepihut.com/products/motozero). I need to supply the Motozero with power from 4.5 to 36 volts as well as the Raspberry Pi Zero.

What is the best way to do accomplish this?

Comment: Could you give an idea of the weight of the drone? Do you have a rough idea of the current the system could draw under load? Most drones use LiPo batteries because of their high voltage output. LiPo cells have a nominal voltage of 3.7 volts, so you would need something like a 9s or 10s (s meaning cells), or multiple batteries in series.However you'd need some type of voltage converter or controller if you want to power the Pi off of the same supply. Sorry I couldn't be more help, I know a bit about drones but close to nothing about using a Pi to control them :D

Comment: Edit - just realized that this post is 3+years old lol

Answer (score 0):

As others asked before, could you provide us with information regarding the size of the motors (and the current they consume)?

The Pi itself will need stable 5V, so I suggest you use a buck (step down) converter to generate 5V for the Pi and the motors from say 3s lipo (11,1V nominal). Buck converters are cheap these days, and found on any website that sells Arduino or Pi stuff.
The Pi zero current consumption is listed here [Power consumption of Pi Zero W?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63519/power-consumption-of-pi-zero-w) so make sure you select a buck that can offer that much current.

I suggest you separate the Pi power from the motors power (use a buck converter for each one), that is a good engineering approach. Also add filter capacitors (mainly in the Pi supply line) of say 100nF for high frequency filtering (remember you are going to be running "high power" motors that can render your power supply full of noise).

P.S.: There is actually a lot of engineering that goes into designing a system, specially a highly unstable like the one you are doing; so maybe you will have to test a bunch of buck converters and configurations before you get a fully functioning product. That is life.