# Is it possible to use same power adapter for Raspberry pi and L293D while conrolling a 3v relay?

Tags: power, pi-zero, relay

i want to control a 3v relay with raspberry pi zero. 
[image: L293D and 3v relay]
I'm using this tutorial:
https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051
My question; different power sources using in this tutorial, a battery pack using for power the motor.
I have a single 5v 600 mA adapter. I want to use this adapter for raspberry pi and relay. Is that works?

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/63535/19949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but i can't  connect relay directly gpio. I have used l293d to control relay and i can connect relay directly l293d. You can use same power adapter for raspberry pi and relay without any problem. 
Additionally you can use this article to control relays: http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/raspberry-pi/simple-raspberry-pi-relay-control-over-the-internet/