# Can I provide 1A, 5V to Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: power-supply, pi-zero-w

I want to design a Power Supply Unit(PSU) for Raspbery Pi Zero W. I will have a camera https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2 connected and running, two relays and few gpio's running.

Camera Consumes around 250mA, RPi idle mode 150mA.

I read here https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#power it states Recommended PSU to be 1.2A
I can design 5V 1A PSU, will it be sufficient? How to calculate power consumption?

I have read these before but still unclear

[Power consumption of Pi Zero W?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63519/power-consumption-of-pi-zero-w)

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-power

If not, could you please share some PSU reference design with inrush | surge protection for 1.2A?

Comment: I do not understand how you can design a PSU without knowing the characteristics of the input power.

Comment: I am really sorry I want to ask how to calculate input power consumption? As recommended by Raspberry Pi, what is Recommended PSU current capacity? How do they recommend then?

Comment: You misunderstand.  How can you design a PSU without knowing the input voltage and whether it is DC or AC etc?

Comment: I will be using 220V 50Hz AC source as a power supply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to calculate power consumption?

You sum all parts that consumes power, example:

```
- Raspberry Pi Z W  230 mA
- Camera            250 mA
- Relay x 2         xxx mA
                    -----
                    xxx mA
```

and so on.

The us addition to get the sum of all consumers and that will be the minimum current needed for a PSU. And off course add some leeway

Reference : http://raspi.tv/2017/how-much-power-does-pi-zero-w-use

> If not, could you please share some PSU reference design with inrush | surge protection for 1.2A?

This is a question for "SE Electrical Engineering".

Comment: Please mark this answer as the answer to your question, if you found it useful.